# Convergence of a series like geometric series

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

The geometric series:
$$ \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} a^n = \frac{1}{1-a},$$
for $|a|<1$. But if I have a series such that
$$ \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \frac{a^{n-1}}{n}.$$
Does this series converges? Thank you for any answer or suggestion.

Comment: Ratio test still gives you the radius of convergence.

Comment: Yes, Comparison for absolute values.

Comment: The series converges for $|a|<1$.

Comment: Multiply by $a$ and take the derivative, and you get $\frac{1}{1-a}$. So your series converges for $|a|<1$ and is equal to $$\frac{-\log(1-x)}{x}$ (or $1$ when $x=0$.)

Comment: This is the [Mercator series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercator_series) for the natural logarithm.

Answer (score 1):

If $a=1$ then what you have is the harmonic series which diverges. It follows that if $|a|>1$ the series will also diverge.

Now, if $ |a| <1$ notice that

$$ \left|\frac{a^{n-1}}{n}\right| \leq \left|a^{n-1}\right|, $$

which implies that

$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left| \frac{a^{n-1}}{n}\right|\leq\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left|a^{n-1}\right|\leq \frac{1}{1-|a|}. $$

so that the series are absolutely convergent and, therefore, convergent.

If $a=-1$ then this is (the negative of) an alternating harmonic series which converges to $-\ln(2)$.

The general solution is:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{a^{n-1}}{n}=-\frac{\ln(1-a)}{a} \;\;\; \text{for all } -1\leq a<1.$$